# Determining functions involved in a definite integral using substitution;

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

The question is the following:

Consider the continuous function $\phi \colon\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and another function $f \colon\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb R$ defined as follow:

$$
f(x) = \int_0^{1/x} \phi (tx^2) dt
$$

Question 1:
Using a proper variable substituition, determine the functions $g$ and $h$ so that the following is true:

$f(x)= (1/{h(x)}) \int_0^{g(x)} \phi (y) dy$

I would like to know how that result is reached, and how you are able to put the $1/x^2$ out of the integral.
I though of substituting $t=tx^2$, but then $dt=dy/x^2$.

Comment: Let us put $y/x^2=t$ in the integral. Then $dt=\frac{1}{x^2}dy$, $y=0$ when $t=0$ and $y=x^2/x=x$ when $t=1/x$. Therefore the integral becomes $f(x)=\int_{x}^{0}\phi(y)\frac{1}{x^2}dy=\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x}\phi(y)dy$. Thus, we can put $h(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$.

Comment: Thanks, but can you just tell me how you put the $1/x$ out of the integral, changing the integration interval, what's the rule?

And why that comes to be needed, I mean, I doesn't the integral get $\int_0^x$ right after the substituition?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable) is the formula. The $1/x^2$  went out of the integral because it is a constant. Notice that the integral is with respect to $y$.

Comment: But shouldn't, after doing the substituition the integral be like $\int_0^x$, instead of $\int_x^0$.

(Notice the last $f(x)$ expression you write, where you put $1/{x^2}$ out of the integral for being a constant... 
I though that would swap the limits of integration).

Sorry, maybe I am missing something...

Comment: You are right. I put the limits of the integral in the wrong places after the first equality. All integrals are supposed to be $\int_{0}^{x}$. Taking the constant $1/x^2$ out didn't change the limits. Me typing in the wrong place did it.